# how to slice a pandas data frame according to column values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with following format:

```
year    col1 
y1      val_1 
y1      val_2
y1      val_3
y2      val_4
y2      val_5
y2      val_6
y3      val_7
y3      val_8
y3      val_9
```

How do I select only the values till year 2 and omit year 3?

I need a new_data frame as follows:

```
   year      col1 
    y1      val_1 
    y1      val_2
    y1      val_3
    y2      val_4
    y2      val_5
    y2      val_6
```

`y1, y2, y3` represent year values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On your sample dataset the following works:

```
In [35]:

df.iloc[0:df[df.year == 'y3'].index[0]]
Out[35]:
  year   col1
0   y1  val_1
1   y1  val_2
2   y1  val_3
3   y2  val_4
4   y2  val_5
5   y2  val_6
```

So breaking this down, we perform a boolean index to find the rows that equal the year value:

```
In [36]:

df[df.year == 'y3']
Out[36]:
  year   col1
6   y3  val_7
7   y3  val_8
8   y3  val_9
```

but we are interested in the index so we can use this for slicing:

```
In [37]:

df[df.year == 'y3'].index
Out[37]:
Int64Index([6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')
```

But we only need the first value for slicing hence the call to `index[0]`, however if you df is already sorted by year value then just performing `df[df.year < y3]` would be simpler and work.